# Storing a vector operation as a character variable

Tags: r

I've got two columns of numerical data, and I want to insert a third column summing them. Easy enough, but I want to assign the summation to a variable *before* doing anything else (long story short: these column names will change all the time [next month they could be `Col4`and `Col5`, for instance], and this is code that will be used by others, and I don't want this crucial step buried deep in the code if I can place it at the top instead). Here's what I've got:

```
sumColumn <- "df$Col1 + df$Col2"
df <- cbind(data.frame("Col1"=2:5, "Col2"=5:8))
df$Col3 <- sumColumn
df
```

Obviously, it returns this:

```
  Col1 Col2               Col3
1    2    5  df$Col1 + df$Col2
2    3    6  df$Col1 + df$Col2
3    4    7  df$Col1 + df$Col2
4    5    8  df$Col1 + df$Col2
```

What I'm looking for is this:

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3
1    2    5    7
2    3    6    9
3    4    7   11
4    5    8   13
```

Is there something I can do with the third line that will coerce the `sumColumn` variable, or some way to create the variable so that it will be interpreted the way I want? Thank you for any help!

Comment: It's better to store the names of the two variables in a character vector. `myCols <- c("Col1", "Col2")`. Then use `df$newCol <- rowSums(df[myCols])`. Easier to store and update this than use the eval/parse paradigm and storing the entire parse in a column.

Comment: Late followup, but this worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
df$Col3 = eval(parse(text=sumColumn))
```

Comment: This is bad practice. OP should not store a character string but an expression (possibly bquote might be useful to OP). The expression can then be evaluated.

Comment: @Roland Can you provide a reference for the reasons not to do this?

Comment: There is an entry in the nice collection of quotes in the fortunes package. The main problems are that such constructs are slow, are difficult to read and understand (hard to maintain such code), gives obscure error messages if something goes wrong, and hinder your growth as an R programmer. R supports storing and evaluation of expressions and with these you can do computations on the language.

Comment: Btw, [this talk](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/useR-international-R-User-conferences/useR-International-R-User-2017-Conference/Taking-Advantage-of-the-Byte-Code-Compiler) explains that eval(parse()) constructs can slow down the byte code compilation which is now enabled by default.

Comment: @Roland Thanks.  This is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to columns by their names using the `df[,"name"]` syntax, for example:

```
df$Col3 <- df[,'Col1'] + df[,'Col2']
```

So if you have the column names in variables `n1` and `n2`, you can do:

```
df$Col3 <- df[,n1] + df[,n2]
```

With `n1 <- 'Col1'` and `n2 <- 'Col2'` defined at the top of your program,
if later the column names change in your data frame,
you can change the values of `n1` and `n2` and the program will continue to work, using the new names.